# Swift UI: array of strings to array of AnyView with Text View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array of strings and I want to convert to array of AnyView which has Text(step). I get the error:

```
Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
func generateViews() -> [AnyView]{
    var views: [AnyView] = []
    ForEach(data.steps, id: \.self) { step in
        views.append(AnyView(Text(step)))
    }
    return views
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably mistaking **ForEach** with **forEach**. Try replacing the code to:

```
func generateViews() -> [AnyView] {
  var views: [AnyView] = []

  data.forEach({
      views.append(AnyView(Text($0.step)))
  })
  return views
}
```

Comment: This works! What's the difference though? why this works and the other does not?

Comment: The diff. is in ForEach you are using. **ForEach** creates and returns a View whereas **forEach** is a simple loop that iterates over the collection. In your implementation, you were simply appending to the array whereas ForEach accepts you to return a View.

Comment: Maybe it helps to think of SwiftUI’s ForEach only as a kind of hack to get around the issue that a real for loop isn’t allowed in function builders. Maybe that will change in a future release

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need AnyView, you need just view:

---

```
func generateViews() -> some View {

    return ForEach(data.steps, id: \.self) { Text($0.description) }

}
```

---

I just add AnyView way as well in case:

```
func generateViews() -> [AnyView] {

     return data.steps.map({ AnyView(Text($0.description)) })

}
```